# Error 500 When pass data from Controller to Ajax Java Spring MVC

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc

I want to collect data from Controller into ajax and show it to modals JSP when button edit clicked. But i got an error 500.

**simulation.jsp**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-edit" data-id="${simulasis.id}">Update</button>
```

**Admin.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.table  .btn-edit').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = {'id': $(this).attr('data-id')};
        $.ajax({
            url: '/backoffice/edit',
            data: id,
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (response) {
                $('#idEdit').val(response.id);
                console.log("success");
            },
            error: function (jqxhr) {
              console.log(this.url);
              console.log(response);
            }
        });
        console.log(id);
        $('#edit-modal-lg').modal();
    });
});
```

**BackofficeController.java**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public Simulasi getById(@RequestParam("id") int id){
        return simulasiService.getSimulasi(id);
    }
```

And I got an error like this,

[image]

Comment: Do some tests to get the URL you have requested directly in your browser. Maybe it will be much expressive and easy to get information. If it is an error with 500 code, then it could be many things but I will look the url params, the request params and the code it should produce with a step by step debugging process.
You will find faster where the bug is, if any

Answer (score 0):

try with following solutions,

declare the data with json format as follows,

```
data: {id : id},
//contentType: "application/json", (omit contentType)
```

return the pure java object from `getById` method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Simulasi getById(@RequestParam("id") int id){
    return simulasiService.getSimulasi(id);
}
```